# Is there a way to intercept intents passed when opening a new activity by another app?

Tags: android, android-intent

Assume that there is an app X which I do not own. Now whenever X switches an activity and passes an intent, is it possible for me to read the contents of the intent (the extra info passed)? Is it even legal to do this?

If it's legal and possible, then how do I go about doing it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this cause each app is running in its own process restricted with its own memory heap.

Answer (score 2):

> is it possible for me to read the contents of the intent (the extra info passed)?

No, not without a custom Android build, some security flaw, or *maybe* on a rooted device. This is for obvious privacy and security reasons, as the data contained in that `Intent` (e.g., extras) is intended to be used only by the sender and recipient.